# Python Script to search names from excel to text and then insert their corresponding values into the excel

Tags: python, excel

I have to write a python script. I have a text file and a excel sheet. Excel sheet contains some files names. The names in the excel are also present in text file. In the text file, there are RAM and ROM memory present corresponding to each of the file names, which is present in the same line in which the file names are. Now i have to read file names from excel sheet and search it in the text file. and then extract the memory present in the text file corresponding to the file names and then put that memory value in the excel. I searched and tried a lot but haven't got any solution. Can anyone help me regarding this.

Example:

Excel Sheet:

```
 **FileName**        **Ram**   **Rom**  

Name1, Name2         

Name3                          

Name4, Name5                

Name7, Name8, Name9
```

Text File:

```
Name      Rom1        Ram1        Ram2       Rom2       Rom3

Name1     56          79          26                    89

Name2     57          80          29         66        

Name3     89                      96                    89

Name4     72          79          26         52         96

Name5     23          32          36         21         89

Name6     98          12                     65         32

Name7     87          10          91                    89

Name8                 99                     59         32

Name8     56          65          45         66         12
```

Ram to be filled in Excel = Ram1 + Ram2

Rom to be filled in Excel = Rom1 + Rom2 +Rom3

Comment: The excel file is in `xls` or `xlsx` format?

Comment: It is in xlsx format

Comment: So, in excel file what Name1, Name2 should contain when data is put there?

Comment: Name1, Name2 are the names of the some files. These files occupy some memory(Ram & Rom) values which is given in the text file. we have to take those memory and insert in the excel in the columns of Rom and Ram.

Comment: I understand, I mean in the excel for row `Name1, Name2` the Ram, Rom should be like this `ram1, ram2` | `rom1, rom2`?

Comment: No, Ram should be the addition of Ram1 and Ram2. While Rom will be Rom1 + Rom2 + Rom3. Now these final Ram and Rom is to be filled in excel.

Comment: Ok, Name1, Name2 are on the same line what should be written in Ram in Rom fields? Value separated by comma or just one value.

Comment: We got the values of Ram & Rom for Name1 & Name2. Now in Ram field of Name1, Name2 value will be addition of Ram of both Name1 & Name2. Same for Rom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> openpyxl

module of python to handle excel read and write. Using this module you can read excel file and using normal file handling you can read text files and do your desired operations

For documentation [check this..](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default)

Comment: Yes i used openpyxl module for excel, but i am not getting how to extract values of Ram and Rom from the text file and add them and then again to insert those values in the excel.

Comment: if you want label-based indexing, `pandas` is way easier than `openpyxl`

Comment: @Prakash. You can do one thing, read the text file line by line. In each line you will get a set of strings, which will be your ROM and RAM details. Then split this string with spaces, then you will get individual values of RAM and ROM

Comment: I have a very lengthy file and going that way won't help. Moreover if u see the text file many values(Ram & Rom) are empty. So, facing the problem of white-space.

Comment: @Prakash. If possible convert the text file in a format in which you can fetch  the data

Comment: I did that but still facing the problem of whitespace.

Comment: @Prakash. If the number of white spaces across the text file is constant, then split based on number of white spaces

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try any code? I would advice you to look at Pandas, it has a nice function to read excel. Then you can extract the information from the pandas dataframe, and write it back to new excel files.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: No, i tried to write my own script but got stuck somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your excel file structure is fixed you can try this:

```
import xlrd
import re
import csv
from xlutils.copy import copy

names = []

w = xlrd.open_workbook('excel_file.xlsx')
s = w.sheet_by_index(0)

names_column = s.col_values(0)
del(names_column[0])

names = []

for name in names_column:
    if re.match(r'Name[1-9]', name):
        tmp = name.split(',')
        tmp = list(map(str, tmp))
        tmp = list(map(str.strip, tmp))
        names.extend(tmp)

# print(names)

names_rom = {}
names_ram = {}

for name in names:
    names_rom[name] = 0
    names_ram[name] = 0

memory = []

with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    reader = csv.reader(text_file)
    for line in reader:
        if len(line) != 0:
            memory.append(line)

# print(memory)

del(memory[0])

processed_memory = []

for line in memory:
    tmp = line[0].split(' ')
    tmp = [item for item in tmp if item != '']
    processed_memory.append(tmp)

# print('PROCESSED_MEMORY:', processed_memory)

for m in processed_memory:
    print('M:', m)
    names_rom[m[0]] = int(m[1]) + int(m[4]) + int(m[5])
    names_ram[m[0]] = int(m[2]) + int(m[3])

# print(names_rom)
# print(names_ram)

wb = copy(w)
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
sheet.write(2, 1, names_ram['Name1'] + names_ram['Name2'])
sheet.write(2, 2, names_rom['Name1'] + names_rom['Name2'])
sheet.write(4, 1, names_ram['Name3'])
sheet.write(4, 2, names_rom['Name3'])
sheet.write(6, 1, names_ram['Name4'] + names_ram['Name5'])
sheet.write(6, 2, names_rom['Name4'] + names_rom['Name5'])
sheet.write(8, 1, names_ram['Name7'] + names_ram['Name8'] + names_ram['Name9'])
sheet.write(8, 2, names_rom['Name7'] + names_rom['Name8'] + names_ram['Name9'])
wb.save('excel_file.xlsx')
```

Note that I did not check the rom and ram data very thoroughly. I sued the libraries: `xlrd`, `xlutils`, `csv` for working with files. This is just to give you an idea how to solve your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this will be helpful if the excel file and the text file is short. Not in my case. But i got some ideas from it.

Comment: @Prakash I could've made my solution more flexible to cover bigger excel and text files, but I think you need to try to solve it yourself. All you need to do is to rework my answer a little bit and solve your problem. I am glad I was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

using pandas

## Reading the excel-file

```
df = pd.read_excel('filenames.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

> df

```
    ram     rom
filename        
Name1, Name2    NaN     NaN
Name3   NaN     NaN
Name4, Name5    NaN     NaN
Name7, Name8, Name9     NaN     NaN
```

## Reading the text file

```
usage_raw = pd.read_csv('data/usage.txt', sep='\s+', index_col=0)
```

> usage_raw

```
    Rom1    Ram1    Ram2    Rom2    Rom3
Name                    
Name1   56  79  26  89.0    NaN
Name2   57  80  29  66.0    NaN
Name3   89  96  89  NaN     NaN
Name4   72  79  26  52.0    96.0
Name5   23  32  36  21.0    89.0
Name6   98  12  65  32.0    NaN
Name7   87  10  91  89.0    NaN
Name8   99  59  32  NaN     NaN
Name9   56  65  45  66.0    12.0
```

## Getting the columns with rom and ram data

```
rom_columns = usage_raw.columns[usage_raw.columns.str.startswith('Rom')]
ram_columns = usage_raw.columns[usage_raw.columns.str.startswith('Ram')]
```

> rom_columns, ram_columns

```
(Index(['Rom1', 'Rom2', 'Rom3'], dtype='object'),
 Index(['Ram1', 'Ram2'], dtype='object'))
```

## Summing for each name

```
usage_df = pd.DataFrame(index=usage_raw.index, columns=['rom', 'ram'])
usage_df['rom'] = usage_raw[rom_columns].sum(axis=1)
usage_df['ram'] = usage_raw[ram_columns].sum(axis=1)
```

> usage_df

```
    rom     ram
Name        
Name1   145.0   105
Name2   123.0   109
Name3   89.0    185
Name4   220.0   105
Name5   133.0   68
Name6   130.0   77
Name7   176.0   101
Name8   99.0    91
Name9   134.0   110
```

## Putting it together

```
for row in df.index:
    df.loc[row] = usage_df.loc[row.split(', ')].sum(axis=0)
```

> df

```
                        ram     rom
filename        
Name1, Name2            214.0   268.0
Name3                   185.0   89.0
Name4, Name5            173.0   353.0
Name7, Name8, Name9     302.0   409.0
```